# How do I make image inside bootstrap 5 col to follow scroll but not below the col itself

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

in the following code the image inside "fixedContainer" is located on the top of the div, but if the sidebar has a large amount of data it is large in height so the user has to scroll. How can I make the image follow the scrolling but not below end of `<div class="col-lg-8">`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWMGbF?ver=ecec&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" height="600" width="50">                                                    
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWMGbF?ver=ecec&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" alt="position-sticky" class="fixed">
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

NOTE: I have edit the post and added a picture to the left with a high height set to it. But the code need to be run in full screen to see the issue, otherwise the col is stacked on top of each other.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: I use Bootstrap 5

Comment: You should include a [example], which includes the sidebar and a large amount of data with perhaps a dummy image so we can see the issue you describe, instead of guess on what it could be.

Comment: Yes I have updated original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `position: sticky` and `top:` css for image

```css
.fixed{
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWMGbF?ver=ecec&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" height="600" width="50">                                                    
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 position-relative">
          <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RWMGbF?ver=ecec&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" alt="position-sticky" class="fixed">
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 500px"></div>
```